# Making Installation Script in Ubuntu

Tags: shell, ubuntu, installation

I am making an install script to setup the web environment, like the following

1. Apache
2. PHP
3. MySQL
4. SSH Components

etc..

I am wondering how I can test my script (as the script must have bugs), how can I restore the state before running the script again?

Thanks for all the advices

Comment: Using a virtual machine?

Comment: Thanks julienc, yes I plan to use VM, but what I need to do is to change the image once I run my script, it may be very troublesome, right?

Comment: Not if you use snapshots: http://www.howtogeek.com/150258/how-to-save-time-by-using-snapshots-in-virtualbox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For testing install scripts/provisioning code (puppet/chef/etc) I would suggest to use **vagrant**.

[Vagrant](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/index.html) provides you with an easy way of starting and destroying virtual machines locally (and not only).

You can use the following vagrant configuration file to test your shell script on ubuntu 12 VM:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "precise64"
  config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box"

  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.101"

  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "lamp-provisioner.sh"
end
```

Then you can:

1. `vagrant up` to start a new vm and run the shell script
2. `vagrant ssh` to inspect the vm state after the shell script was executed
3. `vagrant destroy` to destroy the VM
4. `vagrant up` to start a new vm again in order to test any changes you might want to add to the script.